# Laravel migration can't create foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to create a foreign key, artisan does not show me any errors, just does not create my foreign key, it's probably my code:

1° table:

```
Schema::create('cooperados', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('nameCoop', 255);
        $table->integer('numCoop');
        $table->string('cpfCoop', 11);
        $table->date('dtCad');
        $table->date('dtDem')->nullable();
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('subscritas', 6, 2);
        $table->decimal('integralizadas', 6,2)->nullable();
        $table->decimal('aintegralizar', 6,2)->nullable();
        $table->enum('status', ['ativo','inativo'])->default('ativo');
    });
```

the foreign key table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('mov', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('idMov');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('id_coop')->unsigned;
            $table->foreign('id_coop')->references('id')->on('cooperados');
            $table->decimal('valor', 6, 2);
        });
    }
```

Comment: You can only index a column as foreign key, after it's creation check doc https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your code from

```
$table->integer('id_coop')->unsigned;
$table->foreign('id_coop')->references('id')->on('cooperados');
```

To:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('id_coop')->index();
$table->foreign('id_coop')->references('id')->on('cooperados')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Or you can also use below code

```
 $table->integer('id_coop')->unsigned()->index();
 $table->foreign('id_coop')->references('id')->on('cooperados')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Or also you can use below

```
$table->bigInteger('id_coop')->unsigned()->index();
$table->foreign('id_coop')->references('id')->on('cooperados')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: can you please explain why we need `index()`?

Comment: @Ishaan here is the link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#:~:text=MySQL%20requires%20indexes%20on%20foreign,columns%20in%20the%20same%20order.

Comment: @SalmanZafar i even tried index but in my case it is not working